# Checking input values for special symbols

Tags: javascript, validation

I am having two text fields in my form. The data to be entered in the field are Name and City respectively. I want to check that the user has not entered any special symbols like !,@,#........ i.e, the only thing user should enter must be belonging to a-z,A-Z, though the user can enter Underscore(_), but no numbers, no special symbols.

I want to check this using JavaScript, how can this be achieved.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A classic problem that's usually solved with the help of regular expressions.

```
var myString = "London";
if (myString.match(/^[a-zA-Z_]+$/)) {
    // Success
}
```

If you want to allow spaces, like for New York, change the pattern to `/^[a-zA-Z_\s]+$/`.

Comment: Be careful, what chars you disallow there. Maybe citizens of e.g. Montréal like to use your form too.

Comment: Google for regular expressions. They're used to match patterns in strings, like your city name. In my example, the match will be successful if the string only contains lowercase/uppercase letters and underscore. If there is anything else, it will fail.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: And what about Saint John’s, Aix-en-Provence or Αθήνα (i.e. Athens)?

Comment: *and*, with some cities accepting money to change their name to a website or email or something, they may even have colons, periods, or @ in their name

Comment: @Edgar Bonet: I am fine with user dropping "'" from his/her name. The cities name is optional, If he can't mention it, he can leave it.

Comment: @bemace: Thats right, but I won't allow user to have a city name with colons, @ or things of the kind. I am fine with pure names(Without spl symbols)